# How to find the primary key of select list

Tags: android, listview

I have to show the name of my data on a listview, and don't show the primary key. Now when I click I will get name, but I want to get the primary key of the data that was clicked.

```
public class list_view extends ListActivity{    
DBAdapter db;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //override method onCreate that Inheritance from Activity Class
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_view);
    db = new DBAdapter(this);

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.row,R.id.label,db.query()));
}           

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method 
    String selection = l.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    Toast.makeText(this, selection, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //show in toast
    }   
}
```

`db.query` only returns the name of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just sent position of list that you've selected to query method then query finally use moveToPosition() to move cursor to information that you want

Comment: best way , finally i got it thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done in the setup you have at the moment. If you want to use an ArrayAdapter to show your data AND return the id, you need to wrap the items in a class which implements both toString() (to generate the label for display) and something like getId() (to get the id).

Comment: i get item's position that was clicked by getItemIdAtPosition() and then move my cursor to item's position by moveToPosition() its work 
now i got id thanks