# Select primary key from listview

Tags: android, listview, primary-key

i used this link [How to find the primary key of select list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8473151/1296361) that shows the Toast message when an item is selected..can anyone please help me how to fetch the primary key of selected item...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what data you are displaying in ListView. But i would suggest you to create **`ArrayList<Object>`** and this way you can have a particular object from that clicked position.

So, once you have object then you can fetch/display any detail you want from this object.

for example, I am having `ArrayList<Student>` where student is an object of user-defined class, containing RollNo, Name, Address, etc. So if you prepare array list this way, then its easy to manage multiple data of a particular object.

Comment: i've used ArrayList and i'm able to view the total no of PK's generated..i want that the item which is checked should display its PK..i've filled it from sqlite database